# How to copy cell value to another sheet base on criteria (Apps Script)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to write some Apps Script to pull only the email addresses which match from an array of companies into another sheet for processing. This should also remove the @company.com extension and leave me with just the username.

So on Sheet 1:

In Column E, we have the Company names under Header: "Company"

In Column D, we have the Email Addresses under Header: "Emails"

On Sheet 2:

In Column A, we need the Username result under Header: "Username"

Currently the below script which should have 2 results, comes back with:
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K8Y3U.png)

Any help with this would be immensely appreciated as I'm losing my mind.

Thank you!

```
function pullUsernames() {
  //Get Sheet1
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");

  //Set Values for Search
  var valuesToWatch = ['Company1','Company2'];
  var range = sheet.getRange(2,5,sheet.getLastRow()-1).getValues();
  var emails = sheet.getRange(2,4,lr-1).getValues();

  //For Loop to match values, etc.
  for(var i=0; i < range.length; i++){
    if(valuesToWatch.indexOf(range[i][0])){;
      var targetSS = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1hpIIgkXMgrlOfYqfS4A3ro8BFQB02dAy5G40Y7vUI2c").getSheetByName("Sheet2");
      var targetRange = targetSS.getRange(i+1,1,targetSS.getLastRow(),1);
      var usernames = String(emails[i][0]).replace("@company.com", "")
      targetRange.setValue(usernames[i][0]);
    } //if
  } //for
} //Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were a bunch of issues in your code and I decided to optimize them. Feel free to modify the code if needed.

#### Issues:

- Both `range` and `emails` can be fetched together instead of separate
- Brought `targetSS` outside the loop since it is only static based on your issue
- I don't quite get your `getRange`, I assume you want to append the usernames on the last row? If so, then use `appendRow` instead.
- Since I didn't use the `array index` now, I used `includes` instead to check if the data is in `valuesToWatch`.
- Your `email` string manipulation is quite hard coded so I replaced it with a better solution, removing anything but the characters before `@`.

#### Code:

```
function pullUsernames() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  // update your targetSS, made it under same ss for easier testing
  var targetSS = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2");

  // set values for search
  var valuesToWatch = ['Company1', 'Company2'];
  // get email and company columns in one go
  var data = sheet.getRange(2, 4, sheet.getLastRow() - 1, 2).getValues();

  // each row of data contains email and company formatted as [email, company].
  data.forEach(function ([email, company]){
    if(valuesToWatch.includes(company))
      // remove anything from @ onwards from email and append at last row
      targetSS.appendRow([email.substring(0, email.lastIndexOf("@"))]);
  });
}
```

#### Sample Data:

[image: sample data]

#### Sample Output:

[image: sample output]

Comment: This is fantastic, thanks for the quick response.